# Binding multiple objects to a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following this tutorial - [http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i2:-adding-comments](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i2%3a-adding-comments). It is building a sample blog app and so far has an `Article` model and is adding a `Comment` model. An `Article` `has_many` Comments.

They want to be able to create the comment using a form on the articles page:

```
<h3>Post a Comment</h3>

<%= form_for [ @article, @comment ] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :author_name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :author_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I don't understand how this form works though. It binds two objects to the form, and it says that it'll submit to `article_comments_path`, which will `POST` to `comments#create`.

How does this work? How does it know what to do when it has two objects? Does the order of the objects in the array matter? Can you have more than two objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably going to use nested resources:

```
resources :articles do
   resources :comments
end
```

`[ @article, @comment ]` is an array which will build a nested route. Like:

```
 /articles/1/comments
```

`article_comments_path` maps to the `index` action (GET) and to `create` action(POST)

do`rake routes` to see what i'm talking about:

```
article_comments_path    GET     /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)    comments#index

                         POST    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)    comments#create
```

So essentially, you use `[ @article, @comment ]` when you have nested resources to create routes helpers. the order of the objects matter as it is `article_comments_path` and NOT `comment_articles_path`.

whether you can bind more than 2 objects to the form, it depends, I think, on how deeply nested are your resources

UPDATE:

you are using a form. and forms are for either to `create` or `update` objects depending on whether the object exists or not. The `submit` button will trigger that. This [article](http://www.buildingwebapps.com/transcript/79330-rails-form-processing) sums it pretty good

"When the user clicks submit on a form, Rails invokes either the create (for a new record) or update (for an existing record) action in the associated controller. Forms are, by default, submitted with an HTTP POST command, and all the information that was entered in the form is provided in a hash called params, which is available to the controller."

Comment: I know *that* it's doing these things, but I don't know how/why. So I could copy the code, but I wouldn't be able to expand off of it. Like I wouldn't know how to delete a comment or edit it or something. I think what I'm missing is how you go from the array to the action of the form.

Comment: Ok, so 1) I wouldn't be using a form to delete, and 2) it'll know whether to `create` or `update` based on the objects that are passed in?

Comment: yes. you don't use a form to delete. let's say you are in the `show` page (articles/1) and reading article one. and at the bottom of the article you have `delete` button. when you click `delete`, it will go to the controller's destroy action. it knows to go there because next to the delete you specified the path to the destroy action.